# Are Mesoamerican feathered serpents considered to be dragons?

Tags: dragons, mesoamerica

Multiple mythologies have the concept of dragons, although their depictions may differ (Western dragons are different from Oriental ones).

Are Mesoamerican feathered serpents also considered to be dragons?

Comment: It might depends on who is doing the considering. But now that you mention it, they do seem quite dragon-like to me.

Comment: The people that claim that "there are dragons in every ancient mythology" often consider any large flying serpent a dragon, most of the time including Quetzacoatl and Kukulkan. Modern dragon as we know them in contemporary fiction do not start to appear until  medieval times, see Saint George and the Dragon.

Comment: @Mauricio hits the mark.  The term is used very loosely